# Script to automatically transfer ether to another address

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, wallet-transfer

Please, can anyone help with a script to use and watch my address for any incoming ether, and once it enters, the script would quickly transfer the ether to another address. 
I would also love to know how to set up and run the script.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest You need to know about [web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/)